# sql query issue for birthdays

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been having this SQL query issue and now wish to clarify it out..
my intention is to pull out all those members whose birthday is between two days irrespective of the year. i use the below query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
         FROM family_member 
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') 
             BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')  
             AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') 
         ORDER BY MONTH(dob), DAYOFMONTH(dob)";
```

this works well as long as the from_month < to_month
but this doesn't work if i wish to pull out the other way - birthdays falling between Dec 1 to Jan 30 (irrespective of year - now no records are retrieved). can you please let me know if i can refine the query for the same.

i use mmysql db

thanks,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: i was able to fix it with the below query - not sure how i missed all this while..
      $sql = "select * from family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-31', '%c-%d') union select * from family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-01-01', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') order by MONTH(dob) desc, DAYOFMONTH(dob) asc";

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have to deal with date ranges crossing the beginning/end of a month:

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM [table]
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = $month
  AND DAY(birthday) BETWEEN $start AND $end
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day

Answer (score 0):

not sure how i missed.. i was able to fix it with below query

```
 $sql = "select * from family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-31', '%c-%d') union select * from family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%c-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-01-01', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') order by MONTH(dob) desc, DAYOFMONTH(dob) asc";
```